# Nest.js and typeorm. Pagination and filtering by item_id

Tags: typescript, service, pagination, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new in Nest and I want to use Pagination of nestjs-typeorm-paginate but filtering the results with an ID.

In my Questions entity I have a column with the item_id related with that question.

This is my Controller method, I need to give that item_id to my paginate method but I don't now how.

```
import { QuestionsService } from 'src/questions/services/questions.service';
import { Questions } from '../models/questions.interface';
import { DeleteResult } from 'typeorm';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { IPaginationMeta, Pagination } from 'nestjs-typeorm-paginate';
import { QuestionsEntity } from '../models/questions.entity';

@Controller('questions')
export class QuestionsController {

    constructor(private QuestionsService: QuestionsService) { }
    
    @Get(':item_id')
    async findAll(
        @Param('item_id') item_id: number,
        @Res() res: Response,
        @Query('page', new DefaultValuePipe(1), ParseIntPipe) page = 1,
        @Query('limit', new DefaultValuePipe(10), ParseIntPipe) limit = 10,
    ): Promise<Pagination<QuestionsEntity, IPaginationMeta> | void> {
        limit = limit > 100 ? 100 : limit;
        const paginatedQuestions = await this.QuestionsService.paginate({
            page,
            limit,
            route: 'item/item_id'
        });
        if (paginatedQuestions)
            return res.status(200).send(paginatedQuestions).end()
        return res.status(404).end('Error! Questions Not Found')
    }
```

And this is my Service, its just that same that is writting in https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typeorm-paginate

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DeleteResult, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { QuestionsEntity } from '../models/questions.entity';
import { Questions } from '../models/questions.interface';
import { paginate, Pagination, IPaginationOptions } from 'nestjs-typeorm-paginate';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionsService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(QuestionsEntity)
        private readonly questionsRepository: Repository<QuestionsEntity>
    ) { }

    async paginate(options: IPaginationOptions): Promise<Pagination<QuestionsEntity>> {        
        return paginate<QuestionsEntity>(this.questionsRepository, options);
    }
```

PD: Sorry for my english and this is my first post, maybe I'm doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method and get all items by item_id with pagination through **findAndCount** method

here is my service.ts file

```
    async getByitem_id(id) {

        var _response: Object = [];

        const take = id.take || 2
        const skip = id.skip || 0
    
        const [result, total] = await this.questionsRepository.findAndCount(
            {
                where: { 
                    item_id: id  
                }, 
            order: { name: "ASC" },
                take: take,
                skip: skip
            }
        );
        _response=result

        return {
            data: _response,
            count: total
        }

    }
```

And here is the controller.ts file.

```
    @Get('/getbyItem_id/:id')
    async getbyItem_Id(@Param('id') id) {
        var _response = null;

        _response = await this.service.getByitem_id(id);

        return _response;

    }
```